# I am trying to set gain for the left and right channels of an audio track so I can play either channel at a time through both speakers

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

To do so I would need to make use of WebAudio API and its ChannelSplitter feature in order to access the individual channels. I would then need to have functions that could set the gain for Left and Right channels so that I only use one at a time and merge the channels back to their original destination (the audio file). However I have been trying for countless hours and can't get any implementation to work so am reaching out to any of you experts available on here!

**The codepen below outlines what I am trying to achieve**

```
<a>https://codepen.io/grahamfalconer/pen/eYdgeBe</a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use the WebAudio API channel splitter for adjusting the Left or Right gain on an audio track?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275343/how-do-i-use-the-webaudio-api-channel-splitter-for-adjusting-the-left-or-right-g)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <audio id="my-audio" src="audio/Squirrel Nut Zippers - Trou Macacq.mp3"></audio>
</body>
<script>
  const context = new AudioContext(),
    audioSource = context.createMediaElementSource(document.getElementById("my-audio")),
    splitter = context.createChannelSplitter(2)
audioSource.connect(splitter);
splitter.connect(context.destination);
merger = context.createChannelMerger(2);

var gainNode = context.createGain();
gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.5, context.currentTime);
splitter.connect(gainNode, 0);

gainNode.connect(merger, 0, 1);
splitter.connect(merger, 1, 0);

var dest = context.createMediaStreamDestination();

merger.connect(dest);

myAudio = document.getElementById("my-audio")
myAudio.play()

</script>
```

Comment: This is not right.  You connect the source to the splitter to the destination.  You need to do source -> splitter -> 2 gain nodes -> merger -> destination.  The two gain nodes control the volume of the two channels.